# How to document the runtime values of Build Variables in Azure DevOps build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In TeamCity it is very easy to see the runtime values of all parameters used by (or more correctly: available to) the build, with those parameters actual values at the time of the build.

Azure DevOps build pipelines also use parameters (they call them variables).  But how can I see what the values of those variables were during the build?

For example, my build pipeline defines a variable called $(agent.builddirectory).  HOw can I see what that variable resolved to?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320689/how-to-get-all-build-variables-and-values-with-vnext-build-in-azure-devops-2019

Answer (score 0):

Edit your pipeline and add one of the following tasks

1. You can use a `Bash` task (requires Bash on the agent) with

```
Type = Inline
Script = env | sort
```

2. For Windows agents only, you can use a `Command Line` task with

```
Tool = cmd.exe
Arguments = /k set
```

Comment: Side note: setting `system.debug = true` doesn't print the variables to the pipeline log.