# How to get all build variables and values with vNext Build in Azure DevOps 2019?

Tags: tfs

Recently, we have upgraded our build server into Azure DevOps 2019 and there are some legacy builds.

Instead of go through each variable one by one and manually check the value.

Are we able to directly pull all of them together in a script?

Comment: Looks like there's [an extension on the marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dutchworkz.DisplayAllVariables#overview) specifically for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of complicated script, you could just simply use a single cmd.exe command **`/k set`** to achieve  your requirement.

[image]

It will print **all of your build variables include customized and system even build agent variable** info alphabetically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TFS Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) to fetch all the build denifions data and print the variables.

A PowerShell script that does it:

```
$url = "http://tfs-server:8080/tfs/collection/team-project/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=4.0&includeAllProperties=true"

$builds = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -UseDefaultCredentials

ForEach($build in $builds.value)

{

    Write-Host "$($build.name)" -ForegroundColor Yellow

    $objMembers = $build.variables.psobject.Properties

    foreach ($member in $objMembers)

    {

        Write-Host "Variable Name: $($Member.Name)"

        Write-Host "Value: $($Member.Value.value)"

    }

    Write-Host "`n"

}
```